# Using names for coordinates in TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to create some figures in tikz with a lot of lines between some points and therefore I define them as coordinates first. Now I want to name the horizontal lines on the left side by using the variable name of the left point, but all the names are at the same spot. How can I correct this behaviour?

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (10,0);

\coordinate (c) at (0,2);
\coordinate (d) at (10,2);

\coordinate (e) at (0,4);
\coordinate (f) at (10,4);

\draw[|-|] (a) -- (b);
\draw[|-|] (c) -- (d);
\draw[|-|] (e) -- (f);

\node[left=5mm of a]  {Random length};
\node[left=5mm of c]  {Original series};
\node[left=5mm of e]  {Bootstrap sample};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TikZ library `positioning` is needed for the syntax `left=5mm of a`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (10,0);

\coordinate (c) at (0,2);
\coordinate (d) at (10,2);

\coordinate (e) at (0,4);
\coordinate (f) at (10,4);

\draw[|-|] (a) -- (b);
\draw[|-|] (c) -- (d);
\draw[|-|] (e) -- (f);

\node[left=5mm of a]  {Random length};
\node[left=5mm of c]  {Original series};
\node[left=5mm of e]  {Bootstrap sample};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Without library `positioning`, there are error messages like:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `o' or `of' (in '5mm of a').
```

Answer (score 3):

If you considers tex on the left sides of lines as labels, than you can shorten your picture code and draw it without help of `positioning library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=5mm]

\coordinate[label=left:Random length]   (a) at (0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (10,0);

\coordinate[label=left:Original series] (c) at (0,2);
\coordinate (d) at (10,2);

\coordinate[label=left:Bootstrap sample](e) at (0,4);
\coordinate (f) at (10,4);

\draw[|-|] (a) edge (b) 
           (c) edge (d) 
           (e)  to  (f);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result is:

[image]